# How to resolve AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, python-imaging-library, pyparsing, carla

```
C:\Coursera\CarlaSimulator\PythonClient\Course1FinalProject>python module_7.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module_7.py", line 26, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyparsing import (Literal, ZeroOrMore, Optional, Regex, StringEnd,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyparsing\__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    __version__ = __version_info__.__version__
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

I was trying to connect the python file for controller of an autonomous car to Carlasimulator. I guess what I am doing is not that necessary. However when I try to call the python file it show like this.

```
Pillow>=3.1.2
numpy>=1.14.5
protobuf>=3.6.0
pygame>=1.9.4
matplotlib>=2.2.2
future>=0.16.0
scipy>=0.17.0
```

These are the requierments for the simulator. Other than Pillow and Scipy I could downgrade the versions of other dependencies. But the version of Pillow and Scipy are newer. However I am still getting the error, seems like the versions are not the problem.
Please help me

Comment: I think there was a related issue under Python 3.6, up to 3.6.7, fixed in 3.6.8.  Are you using a recent Python version?

Comment: that maybe the reason. I am using python 3.6.0. But since i downgraded the matplotlib to a lower version, I could run the python file without error. thanks for the feedback anyways. I will try upgrading python incase of similar error.

Answer (score 1):

I could run the file just installing older version of matplotlib. I am a beginner in this field, but I guess it's with the compatibility of Carla and version of matplotlib. when I installed matplotlib 2.2.4 everything works fine. hope this would be useful.